# How to create dynamic playlist.js for theme audio player using php?

Tags: php, media-library

This is a follow-up question, but I'll include the code from before.
I have a playlist script...

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
var myPlaylist = [
 <?php
 foreach ($audiofiles as $file)
 {
   echo "{
        mp3:'".$file->guid."',
        title:'".$file->post_title."',
        artist:'"."',
        rating:5,
        buy:'".$file->post_excerpt."',
        price:'"."',
        duration:'"."',
        cover:'"."'
    },"
; }
?>
];
</script>
```

The problem, as you can probably see, is that the php puts a comma after the final audio file in the playlist, and that distupts the syntax and the whole thing doesn't load.
I'm sure it's a simple fix, maybe create a different "echo" for the last item in the list? How would I do this?

Comment: This is an AJAX question, not a wordpress question. Stackoverflow is where you want to be.

Comment: Oops! Thanks for the tip. Sorry about that.

Comment: and please notice that i've updated my original answer in regards of guid usage...even if guid works for the moment..you should know that it can break easily and there are better ways.
this question: see @kaiser answer and especially the json_encode part. it's the way to go.

Comment: Not even a ajax Q. It's a php Question. (Pop off the last element with `array_pop` before looping through them). Btw: Don't open another Q on SO. I already flagged it. And yes, **listen to what @ungestaltbar says**.

Comment: note that you can do : ``echo "$people->john drank some $juices[0] juice.".PHP_EOL;``

Comment: here's a better title for your question: "How do I omit the seperator after the last element when iterating using foreach?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($audiofiles as $file) {
  echo "{
    mp3: " . json_encode($file->guid) . ",
    title: " . json_encode($file->post_title) . ",
    artist: '',
    rating: 5,
    buy: " . json_encode($file->post_excerpt) . ",
    price: '',
    duration: '',
    cover: ''
  }";
  if ($i++ !== sizeof($audiofiles)-1) echo ",";
}
```

Are you sure you couldn't figure this out yourself?